Need help in Upgrading an Aspire XC-1780 PSU and GPU compatibility
I'm a bit confused (and new to this) and I wanted to double check I'm not about to do something stupid.
I have an Acer Aspire XC-1780 and I want to install a graphics card. I'm aware of some constraints - basically that it has a 180W power supply and the case is really small.

So, first I'm pretty sure I need to upgrade the PSU. My understanding is that the best I can do with this machine is a 300W supply (either DC.3001B.00A or DC.30018.00C) - although to my eyes they are virtually identical (is there a difference?) - there are bigger PSUs out there, but they won't fit? Is this correct?

Second, I understand that the recommended GPUs are either a GEFORCE 1030, or a GEFORCE GT 730. Can anybody confirm that this is correct?

Finally - can anybody tell me of any alternative setup using non-acer approved hardware? - given the constraints of space and power


Sorry for the long question, I'm just a bit twitchy about getting this wrong…

Hi Will,  I voted to close the question and the robot closed it.  This site works best with one question at a time.  Use multiple posts if you have to.  Once you have corrected this, the question can be voted on to reopen.
